# Why i am getting 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors, xmlhttprequest

I am getting this error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/api/auth/register' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

```
<template>
    <div class="container mt-2">
                <form autocomplete="off" @submit.prevent="register" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': has_error && errors.email }">
                        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="user@example.com" v-model="email">
                        <span class="help-block" v-if="has_error && errors.email">{{ errors.email }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': has_error && errors.password }">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" v-model="password">
                        <span class="help-block" v-if="has_error && errors.password">{{ errors.password }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': has_error && errors.password }">
                        <label for="password_confirmation">Conform Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" v-model="password_confirmation">
                    </div>
                     <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="has_error && !success">
                      <p v-if="error == 'registration_validation_error'">Validation error</p>
                      <p v-else>Please fill all the fields to get registered</p>
                     </div>
                     <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
                    <div class="text-center pb-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="background-color:#00A7F5;border:none;">Register</button>
                    </div>
          </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password_confirmation: '',
        csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
        has_error: false,
        error: '',
        errors: {},
        success: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      register() {
        var app = this
        this.$auth.register({
          data: {
            email: app.email,
            password: app.password,
            password_confirmation: app.password_confirmation
          },
          success: function () {
            app.success = true
          },
          error: function (res) {
            app.has_error = true
            app.error = res.response.error
            app.errors = res.response.errors || {}
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

if fails, response from controller

```
 $a = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'  => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
 if ($a->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'errors' => $a->errors()
            ], 422);
        }
```

if everything ok then

```
return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
```

Please let me know whats wrong with this and is there any better way to handle error. Please share link then, i am not able to handle error correctly.
All helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

CORS policy checks strictly on domain plus port. So make both the same will be the solution.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Host the service under the same site address. CORS solution is not a good choice. For a small project, it's unnecessary. For a large project, it's simple for security.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CORS Service Provider to your project, like this: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors